# How to handle logged in userId from the web app when joining to the telegram group of the site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a web site that has a telegram button with invitation link to the telegram group.
Created a bot using Botfather for listnening new member events.

Is there a way to catch a userId that has joined to the group from website in order to save a username in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not any direct methods, but there is an *indirect method* to solve this problem:

**On Your Website**
change link to `https://t.me/@your_bot_username?start=webname-group_name`

**In Your Bot**
check start command and split its arguments and first argument will website and 2nd will group username
and then send him group link, also save userid in your database.